# How to Add an event handler a DLL compiled button from one WPF project to another?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 WPF projects that I'm testing DLL calling from. 2 are class libraries (DLLs) that have a label and a button (so both have essentially the same thing, one has a purple button and one has a grey one). I have implemented the following for reading in the DLL and loading up the appropriate one in the single remaining fresh WPF application that will be taking in a WPF DLL. Part I haven't quite worked out yet, is how do I handle when the button is clicked from the WPF DLL? Not sure what to do... Here is the code for the WPF project that isn't a DLL.

This is for flexibility with our new project.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPFSandBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        UserControl userControl = null;
        InstrumentEnum instrumentType = InstrumentEnum.Invalid;
        string dllToLoad = null;

        // When we first initialize our WPF app, in the constructor we can
        // allow a config file (such as a json) to be read and load up
        // an appropriate user control view
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadJson();
            LoadRunTimeDLL();
        }

        private void ReadJson()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("../../Config/Config.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

                foreach (var entry in jsonData)
                {
                    if (entry.Key == "InstrumentType")
                    {
                        Enum.TryParse(entry.Value, out instrumentType);
                    }
                    else if (entry.Key == "DllToLoad")
                    {
                        dllToLoad = entry.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void LoadRunTimeDLL()
        {
            string assemblyName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.dll", 
                new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName, dllToLoad);

            if (assemblyName != null)
            {
                Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName);
                Type[] tlist = asm.GetTypes();
                foreach (Type t in tlist)
                {
                    if (t.Name == "UserControl" + instrumentType.ToString())
                    {
                        userControl = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as UserControl;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (userControl != null)
                {
                    contentControl.Content = userControl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a user control i created for the WPF DLL project.

```
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFPurpleButtonTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="colourButton" Content="Switch DLL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="91" Margin="284,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243" Background="#FFDC00FF" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label x:Name="colourName" Content="PURPLE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="93" Margin="284,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" Foreground="#FFDC00FF"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the MainWindow.xaml for the main WPF project.

```
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFSandBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="contentControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This seems a very odd way of doing things.  I feel there is likely a better way.  But as it stands... Would mef not be appropriate? Your dll would essentially implement an interface and you could probably use that to drive things. Where is the code that does stuff when you click the generic button supposed to go? In the main parent or the class library? Because a click is a routed event. You can just handle it in the parent and pass something via the button's tag that references whatever you want to do. Or get a reference to the parent from the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... what you are trying to do is to access the button inside the User Control... 
I hope I understood your question...

This is what I tried...

First of all, I didn't use the fancy stuff, Reflection but created a DLL which contains a User Control, then added the DLL into the project reference of the WPF application.

This is the code of the DLL.

**UserControl1.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfCustomControl.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="innerButton" Content="Click Me!" />
</Grid>
```

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerButtonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InnerButton", typeof(Button), typeof(UserControl1));

    public Button InnerButton
    {
        get { return (Button)GetValue(InnerButtonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InnerButtonProperty, value); }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InnerButton = innerButton;
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the WPF application. (Don't forget to add the DLL reference.)

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="HookupTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfcustomcontrol="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControl;assembly=WpfCustomControl">
<Grid>
    <wpfcustomcontrol:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        userControl.InnerButton.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you!");
    }
}
```

The key point is to use dependency property for the WPF application to hook up with the reference inside the DLL.

I reckon this would be the same way when you use the Reflection.

Hope this would be a help.

Comment: Thanks Eugene! Quick question. If we were dynamically loading in the DLL at runtime where it could be one DLL or another based on a config, how can we parameterize the MainWindow.xaml to accept one DLL usercontrol or another DLL usercontrol?

Comment: @slickchick2 If I were you, I would put a list control in the xaml to bind a collection of user controls of the DLLs. for instance, the LoadRuntimeDLL returns the user control you want to load up and put it into the collection in the code behind or view model. and the collection is bound to the view (Xaml).

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your response :) "the LoadRuntimeDLL returns the user control you want to load up and put it into the collection in the code behind or view model. and the collection is bound to the view (Xaml)." This bit.. how can I go about doing that? Not entirely sure where to start

Comment: also not sure about this bit. How can I inject the DLL it's found into this bit?     xmlns:wpfcustomcontrol="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControl;assembly=WpfCustomControl">
<Grid>
    <wpfcustomcontrol:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl"/>
</Grid>

Answer (score 0):

I have added another answer here for your questions in the comment, as I couldn't put the source code in the comment.

In the MainWindow.xaml, let's replace grid with the list control.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic" />
```

And in the MainWindow.xaml.cs code-behind, let's code like this.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var ucs = new List<UserControl1>();

    ucs.Add(new UserControl1());
    ucs.Add(new UserControl1());
    ucs.Add(new UserControl1());

    ic.ItemsSource = ucs;
}
```

I know this code is not nice at all, but tried to explain what my answer was meant.
I assume that you are trying to implement an application which you can attach a module into it dynamically as you reflect and instantiate the module in the LoadRunTimeDLL method.
So you might be able to let the method return the module instance, then add it in the the list (ucs in this example).

This link might be helpful for you; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=netframework-4.8

and hope you can find a similar example here for your project.
https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples

Comment: Hi Eugene, this makes sense, however UserControl1 is not available to the main WPF application, so not sure how i'd go about that... unless I add a reference to the project for every DLL...

Comment: xmlns:wpfcustomcontrol="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControl;assembly=WpfCustomControl"> this is essentially the problem - WpfCustomControl will change.... it can be one or the other depending on which DLL is loaded...